# How can I check if this heat valve is on

Tags: heating

Am I allowed to show photos here? There has been no heat in my stabilized apt all day and I suspect something is wrong. I wonder if it's possible for the super to close the valves on stabilized tenants so we freeze out. I have a valve and a know. Have photos but dont know if I'm allowed to show them.

Comment: Photos are _strongly_ encouraged! [Edit] your question, then drag the pics in (if you're on a computer), or hit the "sun & mountain" icon above the text edit box and select your picture. Also, please take the [tour] and read up on [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and change your question to ask a clear, specific question. It's often helpful to indicate where in the world you live (city/state/country), as things differ in different places around the world.

Comment: Being possible and being allowed are two different things.  Quite a few places have regulations saying heat must be on/working by a certain date/temperature, unless for timely repair.  Hopefully you are in one of these places that have regulations or that repairs are needed.  Contact super in case they do not know heat is off in your place so they can fix it or report it to local regulatory department if they are playing games.  Heating repairs can take some time.

Comment: If no heat then it is off somewhere.  I imagine this is building heater than room heater(contained totally inside the room plus power/fuel).